# How to interpret Hill estimate of tail index

Tags: r, distributions, extreme-value, kurtosis, heavy-tailed

I'm seeking a non-technical explanation of how to interpret the Hill estimate of the tail index for fat-tailed data, and, if possible, some explanation of seemingly contradictory results that different R functions produce.

I have watched some tutorials of tail index estimation and extreme value theory (e.g., https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZPqQPQQZAk&t=18s, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o-cpu1IH3tM) and have been looking through the documentation of R functions for calculating the Hill estimate of the tail index (namely, `evir::hill` and `ReIns::Hill.kopt`), but am having trouble making sense of results I get.

Here's an example where I pose more concrete questions:

#### Step 1

First, I load the relevant packages and create three log normal distributions with varying tail lengths, `dat_long`, `dat_longer`, and `dat_longest`.

```
# packages
library(ReIns)
library(evir)
library(tidyverse)
library(cowplot)

set.seed(42)

# create three distributions with long, longer, and longest tails
dat_long <- rlnorm(n=500, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1)
dat_longer <- rlnorm(n=500, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 10)
dat_longest <- rlnorm(n=500, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 20)

# view distributions
a <- ggplot()+geom_histogram(aes(x=dat_long))
b <- ggplot()+geom_histogram(aes(x=dat_longer))
c <- ggplot()+geom_histogram(aes(x=dat_longest))
cowplot::plot_grid(a, b, c, ncol = 1)
```

[image]

#### Step 2

Then I use `evir::hill` to generate Hill plots for each distribution.

```
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
hill(dat_long)
hill(dat_longer)
hill(dat_longest)
```

[image]

#### Step 3

Now I need to select the optimal threshold. In [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GZPqQPQQZAk&t=7s) it's explained that you should look for where the plot stabilises. So eyeballing the above plots, I'd conclude that the optimal order statistic (or k) for `dat_long` would be around 145 and the alpha would be about 1.5. For `dat_longer` the optimal order statistic would be around 189 and alpha would be about 0.15. For `dat_longest` the optimal order statistic would be around 93 and alpha would be about 0.10.

**From this I would conclude that, as a general rule of thumb, the Hill estimate decreases as tail length increases. Is this a valid conclusion?**

#### Step 4

Since I'm not really confident with the "eyeballing" method, I turn to `ReIns::Hill.kopt`, which as the documentation states selects the optimal threshold for the Hill estimator by minimising the Asymptotic Mean Squared Error (AMSE). This function outputs the optimal order statistic as `kopt` and the optimal Hill estimate as `gammaopt`.

So I apply it each distribution and get the following:

```
> Hill.kopt(dat_long)$kopt
[1] 60
> Hill.kopt(dat_long)$gammaopt
[1] 0.4077617
> 
> Hill.kopt(dat_longer)$kopt
[1] 92
> Hill.kopt(dat_longer)$gammaopt
[1] 5.167227
> 
> Hill.kopt(dat_longest)$kopt
[1] 1
> Hill.kopt(dat_longest)$gammaopt
[1] 0.03570751
```

**Why do these results have no resemblance to the results I arrived at after eyeballing the Hill plots with `evir::hill`?**

#### Step 5

Given the weird results in Step 4, I checked if there was any relationship between the optimal Hill estimate returned by `Hill.kopt` and tail length (in this case, `sdlog`). As the plot below shows, it seems like the answer is no.

```
# calculate optimal Hill estimate for distributions 
# with sdlog = {1,2,3,...20}. i.e., varying tail length
hills <- NULL
for(i in 1:20){
  dat <- rlnorm(n=500, meanlog = 0, sdlog = 1)
  h <- Hill.kopt(dat)$gammaopt
  hills <- rbind(hills, c(i, h)) %>% as.data.frame()
}

# plot optimal Hill estimate (gamma) over tail length (sdlog)
names(hills) <- c("sdlog", "gamma")
ggplot(hills, aes(x=sdlog, y=gamma))+
  geom_point(size = 3, alpha = 0.7)+
  geom_smooth(method = "lm")+
  theme_minimal()+
  labs(y = "Hill Estimate (gamma)",
       x = "Tail Length (sdlog)")
```

[image]

**How should I interpret/reconcile these results?**